# Ubuntu 16.04 snap install error

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, snap

I'm having problems installing `snap-packages` on Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

For example, when I try to install `hello-world`, it downloads `ubuntu-core` and then throws this error:

```
~$ sudo snap install hello-world
64.64 MB / 64.64 MB 
[======================================] 100.00 % 
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Make snap "ubuntu-core" available to the system (can not set next boot: cannot determine bootloader)
```

I have no idea what I should do.
I've tried googling it, but I seem to be the only one having trouble with it. =(

Comment: Did you install `ubuntu-core`? `sudo apt install ubuntu-core`

Comment: No I did not. I try.

Comment: Well, then, install it with `sudo apt install ubuntu-core`

Comment: Um, there are not `ubuntu-core` itself but many `ubuntu-core-*` packages like `*-config`, `*-launcher`, `*-libs` & etc. Tried `ubuntu-core-snapd-utils` nothing changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1580403) that was already [fixed](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd/commit/4f497cc298fd163926731ecc0dcae69e22fd5bd7) in the code base.

There will be a new stable release update (SRU) soon. Updating your `snapd` once this is out should get rid of the problem.

Sorry for the trouble.